# Pass and return ID to method

Tags: c#, methods, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate xml file that have unique HEX ID through it. for this I used simple method

```
public string CalcXML_ID()
        {
            string Return_ID;

            cl_XML_ID = cl_XML_ID + 1;
            Return_ID = cl_XML_ID.ToString("X");

            return Return_ID;
        }
```

in my main I call this **CalcXML_ID** three times (I get ID's 1, 2 and 3). Then I call **xmlElement** method from another class, which needs also to have this unique ID **X** times. after that I call my **CalcXML_ID** method again two times.
my problem is how to pass the ID to the **xmlElement** method and getting back the last used ID so that I can continue from there to use the ID for the remaining 2 times.
fyi **xmlElement** return xmlElement as it named.
To make it simple, I have this xml document and node with ID:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement SW_Blocks_FCNode = doc.CreateElement("SW.Blocks.FB");
SW_Blocks_FCNode.SetAttribute("ID", CalcXML_ID()); //ID return value of 1 here

//ObjectList
XmlNode ObjectListNode = doc.CreateElement("ObjectList");
SW_Blocks_FCNode.AppendChild(ObjectListNode);
```

then I call the method form other class and pass my ID to it

```
XmlElement MultilingualTextNode = XML_MultilingualText(doc, "Comment", "", CalcXML_ID()); // The ID used twice inside this method so it should be 2 and 3
ObjectListNode.AppendChild(MultilingualTextNode);
```

after that I have the following:

```
XmlElement CompileUnitNode = doc.CreateElement("CompileUnit");
        CompileUnitNode.SetAttribute("ID", CalcXML_ID()); //The ID here has to continue and it should be 4
```

then I continue my code. the problem is that the ID doesnot continue in the generated file.

Answer (score 0):

For this, cl_XML_ID needs to static, you need to have something like this:

```
public static SomeStaticClass
{
     public static int cl_XML_ID = 0; 

     public static string CalcXML_ID()
        {
            string Return_ID;

            cl_XML_ID = cl_XML_ID + 1;
            Return_ID = cl_XML_ID.ToString("X");

            return Return_ID;
        }

}
```

Now no matter where you call the method from it will continue to increase `cl_XML_ID` from the number it was left off.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to be more clear. This didn't work for me